# Is there a way to access the reference of a variable by its name in c#

Tags: c#

I'm passing list of parameters and values to Class_A from Class_B. Class_A has to set the values of parameters whose names are included in parameters.

```
struct Parameter
{
    public Parameter(string n , object v, Type t){Name = n; Value=v; TypeOfParam = t;}
    public string Name;
    public object Value;
    public Type TypeOfParam;
}
Class_A 
{
    public Class_A(List<Parameter> parameters)
    {
        // needed code to set variables values
    }
    public int param1{get; set;}
    public double param2{get; set;}
}

Class_B
{
    List<Parameter> params = new List<Parameter>(){new Parameter("param1", 12, typeof(int)), new Parameter("param2", 20.2f, typeof(double))};

    Class_A classA = new Class_A(params);
}
```

is there a way to access the reference of a variable by its name and set its value?

a solution like this is prefered:

```
var variable = (parameter.TypeOfVariable)(GetVariableReferenceByName(parameter.Name));
variable = parameter.Value;
```

rather than something like this:

```
GetField(parameter.Name).SetValue(parameter.Value);
```

but both solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can actually do this with System.Reflection but you cannot do this inside a constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Reflection to achieve this

```
        public void MapValues(object dst, List<Parameter> source)
        {
            var dict = source.ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x);

            var fields = dst.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();
            fields.ForEach(x =>
            {
                var param = dict.ContainsKey(x.Name) ? dict[x.Name] : null;
                if(param != null)
                    x.SetValue(dst, param.Value);
            });
        }

        public Class_A(List<Parameter> parameters)
        {
            MapValues(this, parameters);
        }
```

If you intent to use the same pattern in other classes it would be better to move MapValues into a different utility class